# how to set SplitPane setOneTouchExpandable expand in only one direction

Tags: java

I set setOneTouchExpandable(true) and setEnabled(false) in my JSplitPane allowing the users only to expand left or right . But what I actually want is to have the the left panel either collapse to the left or stay at the default position. (that's why i set setEnabled(false)).

is there a simple way to achieve this? Any help or snippet of code is welcome!

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is "no".

The long answer is "yes", with lots of work that might not ultimately meet your long term needs.

I've had a dig around the code and found that the "one touch" arrows are constructed by the `BasicSplitPaneDividerUI` (in most cases).  As part of it's responsibility, it creates the two resize buttons.

There is no property that you supply that would allow you to tell this UI delegate to only render a single arrow OR any way to trap the action event that occurs.

So, that leaves you with two choices.

1. You can create your own UI delegate and implement the functionality you desire.  This of course runs the risk of producing a UI which no longer matches that of the remaining UI and you also have to take into consideration how that would effect any other split panes within your application.
2. Use a little brute force.  Basically, you want to walk the `JSplitPanes` container's hierarchy and locate any JButtons.  You then either want to attach you own action listeners to them and or replace them altogether.